# In Recycler view items changing automatically without doing anything

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
public class SAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <SAdapter.SHolder>{

    TextView textViewProfileNameFeed,textViewTimeFeed, textViewDZCount, textViewFB, textViewTW, textViewS, textViewFeedLocation, buttonPlayVideo;

    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    ImageView imageViewProfilePicFeed, imageViewBodyFeed;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayoutroot;

    private RecyclerItemClickListener clickListener;

    Context mContext;

    private List<SModel> sList = Collections.emptyList();

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

    boolean isPlaying = false;

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


    public SAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, List<SModel> sList) {

        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        this.sList = rsList;

        Log.d(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>","sList>>>>"+sList);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mainActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }


 @Override
    public SHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

//        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(mainActivity).inflate(R.layout.card, null, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        itemView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        initFont(itemView);

        initFont(itemView);

        return new SHolder(itemView);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Override
public SHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SHolder holder, int position) {
    // you probably don't need to set the layout params here...
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    initFont(holder.itemView);
}
```